# Anonymous code blocks in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Is there a way to use anonymous code blocks in Groovy? For example, I'm trying to translate the following Java code into Groovy:

```
{
  int i = 0;
  System.out.println(i);
}
int i = 10;
System.out.println(i);
```

The closest translation I can come up with is the following:

```
boolean groovyIsLame = true
if (groovyIsLame) {
  int i = 0
  println i
}
int i = 10
println i
```

I know anonymous code blocks are often kind of an antipattern. But having variables with names like "inputStream0" and "inputStream1" is an antipattern too, so for this code I'm working on, anonymous code blocks would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know groovy so can't answer your question directly, but why not refactor your code to get rid of your anonymous code blocks?  Sounds like a better choice to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use anonymous code blocks in Groovy but the syntax is ambiguous between those and closures. If you try to run this you actually get this error:

> Ambiguous expression could be either a
>   parameterless closure expression or an
>   isolated open code block;    solution:
>   Add an explicit closure parameter
>   list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to
>   be treated as an open block by giving
>   it a label, e.g. L:{...} at line: 1,
>   column: 1

Following the suggestion, you can use a label and it will allow you to use the anonymous code block. Rewriting your Java code in Groovy:

```
l: {
  int i = 0
  println i
}
int i = 10
println i
```

Comment: Well, it's hardly "anonymous" anymore when you've given it a name, is it? :)

Comment: Thanks, this is a little cleaner, and replaces the unnecessary "if else" with an unnecessary label. Slightly more concise.

Comment: @Michael If the label were changed to anon: then maybe no-one will notice :)

Comment: even if freedom on labels might be as vast as the related symbol space, its still free form and thus no recognizable design is put into place with that. even reusing a big variety of natural or syntactical words might pop up. and the pretty bad question of looking for a reference of those lable might come up. - its not at all desired to allow that label to be used anywhere - and re-using of labels (if possible at all) might be even more an issue.

Comment: I tried to follow the suggestion of using this label method and I got for example:
"Statement labels may not be used in build scripts." any idea?

Answer (score 8):

```
1.times {
    // I'm like a block.
}
```

Comment: thats a very sounding solution in terms of readability - lets assume the constant value will resolve to zero code overhead for state of the art compiler results.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
({
 int i = 0
 println i
}).()

int i = 10
println i
```

I don't have a Groovy installation at hand, but that should do.

Comment: Yes, this works fine. The only drawback when comparing this to Chris's solution above, is that the stack trace is a little messier when an exception happens within the anonymous block. But this is a good solution too, thanks!

Comment: You can also get rid of the .call() and just replace it with ()

Comment: I'm curious, does `{int i = 0}.()` works also? ( I mean without the surrounding parenthesis?

Comment: Replacing the .call() with () is valid. Removing the surrounding parentheses is not valid; this results in the "ambiguous expression" compiler error mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

In Groovy, those braces constitute a closure literal. So, no can do. Personally, I'd consider having to give up anonymous blocks for getting closures a very good deal.

Comment: You can use anonymous code blocks in Groovy. See my answer for details and example.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add **if(true)**

```java
if(true) {
  int i = 0;
  System.out.println(i);
}
int i = 10;
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common need for an anonymous block is for additional (possibly shadowing) bindings using `def`.  One option is to create a dictionary equivalent of your bindings and use `.with`.  Using the example given in the question:

```
[i:0].with {
  println i
}

int i = 10
println i
```

This gives you a lisp styled `let` block