# Using sub scopes in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In Java/C++, you can introduce subscopes, useful if you have copy-pasta code that you really don't want to change:

```
public void function() { 
    Map<String, Person> ... 

   {  
      Person obj ... 
      ... 
      map.add(obj)
   }
   {  
      Person obj ... 
      ... 
      map.add(obj)
   }

}
```

Only to avoid stupid repetition errors where you forget to change variable1 to variable2.  I'm primarily using this in testcases.

In Groovy, however, this creates closures, and does not behave in the same fashion.  Is there a Groovy way to do this I'm missing?

Comment: Can you add the actual test case written in Groovy to portray properly what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To use a Java code block in Groovy, you need to label the code block.

```
public void function() { 
    Map<String, Person> ... 

   a: {  
      Person obj ... 
      ... 
      map.add(obj)
   }
   b: {  
      Person obj ... 
      ... 
      map.add(obj)
   }

}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670785/anonymous-code-blocks-in-groovy).